# AUGraph on iOS takes seconds to start again after a pause (stop) using TAAE

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-audio, mixer

My app is on iOS 8.3 (iPad and iPhone) and using The Amazing Audio Engine. I'm buffer loading 24 audio files and assigning their output to various channels on a connected USB audio device. Right now I'm testing with a Scarlett 2i|4, but this also happens on the Apogee Duet and two different PreSonus AudioBox units - the 44VSL and the 1818VSL.

The first time I call `[engine play]` aka AUGraphStart(graph), the playback begins immediately. Then I call `[engine stop]` aka `AUGraphStop()`. The next time I call `[engine play]` aka `AUGraphStart()`, it takes about 4 seconds before playback begins, and the channels on the USB device click a few times.

The channels also click a few times when the device is first plugged into the iPad or iPhone.

This issue does not happen on the Speakers or the Headphone routes -- only when a USB device is plugged in and used.

Any ideas why the `AUGraphStart()` call after `AUGraphStop()` takes 4 seconds before it starts playing?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just figured it out -- it's a bug in `TAAE`. It's also calling a `AudioUnitStop` on the `remote_IO` unit. You have to bypass `TAAE` stop and call the graph directly.